# String validation in C++

Tags: c++, string, validation, while-loop

Hi i'm trying to figure out some validation for a small homework assignment in c++.

I am using char arrays.

First is taking in the car's registration. I need it in the format of (year)(year)(letter)(num)(num)(num)(num). This is an Irish car registration if anyone is confused. The problem is that it takes me into the while loop no matter what.

```
printf("Enter the car's registration: ");
        scanf("%s", aCar->carRegistration);
         do
         {
            printf("Error (yyDxxxx) Enter a Car Registration again: ");
              scanf("%s", aCar->carRegistration);  
         }while((isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[0])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[1])) ||  (isdigit(aCar->carRegistration[2])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[3])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[4])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[5])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[6])));
```

My second problem is when I'm ensuring only certain models are entered. i.e Fiesta, Focus and Mustang as i'm pretending it is a Ford dealership.

```
        printf("Enter your car's model (Must be either Fiesta, Focus or Mustang): ");
        scanf("%s", aCar->model);
        while(!(aCar->model == "Focus") || (aCar->model == "Fiesta") || (aCar->model == "Mustang"))
        {
            printf("Error Your car is not a valid model (Must be either Fiesta, Focus or Mustang). \nPlease re-enter: ");
              scanf("%s", aCar->model);  
         }
```

However it says there is an error no matter what I enter. When im done this I want to attach  the word "Ford" to the start. Thanks.

Thank you my first problem was solved by using a while loop instead of a do while.

Here is the code for my answers:

```
 while(!((strcmp(aCar->model, "Focus")) || (strcmp(aCar->model, "Fiesta")) || (strcmp(aCar->model, "Mustang"))))
        {
            printf("Error Your car is not a valid model (Must be either Fiesta, Focus or Mustang). \nPlease re-enter: ");
              scanf("%s", aCar->model);  
         }
```

and

```
while((isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[0])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[1])) ||  (isdigit(aCar->carRegistration[2])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[3])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[4])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[5])) || (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[6])))                      
         {
            printf("Error (yyDxxxx) Enter a Car Registration again: ");
              scanf("%s", aCar->carRegistration);  
         }
```

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: First, we have no idea whether that pointer "aCar" is valid or not, we don't know what an aCar is, etc.  Please post your "aCar" class, and how you initialized that pointer.

Comment: For the first part of your question, it _takes you into the while loop no matter what_ because you are using a `do while` loop.  It will always go into the `do` block first and then check the `while` condition.  You should modify it to an actual while loop rather than a do while loop.

Comment: Why are you using `strcat`, `printf` and `scanf` in a C++ program? You should be using/learning the C++ way of doing things.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` to make sure that you read what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First section: you are using a do/while.

This will always run the loop once, then check to see if it runs again.

Use a WHILE loop or a FOR loop to check before entering the loop.

Second section:

> aCar->model == "Focus"

The '==' command is not used for strings. Instead, use the strcmp function.
Use this code:

```
strcmp(aCar->model, "Focus") == 0 //Is *true* if they are the same.
```

See this explanation:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Ironic how you got this wrong. Should be `!strcmp(aCar->model, "Focus")` or the more readable variant `strcmp(aCar->model, "Focus") == 0`

Comment: Also: we don't know what `model` is, and if it really is C++, he *should* be using `==` for "strings" which are `std::string`. He just should not be using the other C functions then.

Comment: My file extension is .cpp so i'm using c++.

Comment: Using strcmp fixed my problem.

I'll provide my code for anyone else who is stuck

Comment: @user2976759 this question is... not strictly correct from a C++ perspective. `==` *is* used for strings, and strings are done with `std::string` instead of C's `char []`.

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1:

Do while will always perform the contents of the loop at least once before evaluating your condition. You would need to change the statement to a while statement where the condition would be checked before it enters the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You say you're learning strings, but you never state what kind of strings.  If it's C++ std::string, then this is incorrect.  If it's char arrays, then this is also incorrect.  So either way, you're wrong:

```
scanf("%s", aCar->model);
    while(!(aCar->model == "Focus") || (aCar->model == "Focus") || (aCar->model == "Mustang"))
```

If you use std::string, then the while() loop condition is valid, but the scanf() will not work since %s means a character pointer, not std::string.

If you're using C character arrays, then  the scanf() should work, but the while loop will fail, since to compare arrays, you use a comparison function such as strcmp().

So which string types is it?  Is it std::string, or char arrays?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise there were other types. it's char arrays

Comment: The "other type" is quite honestly, the type you should be learning, and that is std::string.  Look at the attempt at the while() loop you wrote -- you instinctively used == to compare the strings, and you know what?  That is exactly how std::string is used.  But instead you've been taught the 'C' char arrays, and for that, you have to go into the depths of possibly overflowing array boundaries, pointer usage, etc..

Comment: I think that instinctive use of using == is because I just started c++ and i've been learning java for 2 years. But perhaps using char arrays has helped me have a greater understanding of string manipulation and accessing characters in strings. That's probably a glass half full outlook though. Thanks for your help Paul and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

I think you missed a negation on your first snippet :

> while( **!** (isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[0]) **&&** isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[1]) **&&**  isdigit(aCar->carRegistration[2]) **&&** isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[3]) **&&** isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[4]) **&&** isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[5]) **&&** isalpha(aCar->carRegistration[6]));

Question 2:

You cannot compare strings with the operator "==". // UPDATE: with std::string

Instead you could úse the compare function from the standard library :

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Or you could use the boost::iequal function with the two types you want to compare

> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/iequals.html

here it would be, for instance :

> boost::iequal< std::string,char const *>( aCar->model, "Focus")

Comment: Of course you __can__ compare strings with `==`. The author probably uses char arrays tho.

Comment: Yeah i'm using char arrays

Comment: With extra parenthesis ? !((aCar->model == "Focus") || (aCar->model == "Fiesta") || (aCar->model == "Mustang"))

Answer (score 0):

1st problem.
Do while loop will run once even if the condition in while is false.You can solve this by either using a while loop or for loop.
2nd problem.
If **model** is a character array then **model** will give an address and therefore the address gets compared to "ford" etc.So use **strcmp**.